# MonitorMixin condition variable -> deadlock

Tags: ruby, multithreading, deadlock

I have a synchronized queue that provides a condition variable.

That condition variable signals when data is added to the queue.

I have 5 threads:

```
Thread.new do
  loop do
    @queue.synchronize {
      cond.wait_until { @queue.has_data? || @queue.finished? }
    }
    # some processing code that can also call @queue.enqueue
  end
end
```

Then I do:

```
@queue.enqueue some_data
@threads.each(&:join)
```

`MyQueue#enqueue` looks like this:

```
def enqueue(data)
  synchronize do
    @pending << v unless queued?(data) || processed?(data) || processing?(data)
    data_cond.signal
  end
end

def finished?
  @started && @processing.empty? && @pending.empty?
end

def has_data?
  !@pending.empty?
end
```

And I get on #join

```
deadlock detected
```

How exactly does this cause a deadlock and how would one fix it?

Comment: What does your code that adds the data look like?

Comment: Hi Fred, I've added the #enqueue code

Comment: what do the has_data / finished methods look like?

Comment: Added has_data? and finished?. Tried wrapping them in `synchronize`, but to no avail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if this is a problem that ***all*** of the threads are blocked on the ***same*** condition variable, and there isnt a thread available to enqueue data, which would release the other threads.

Based on the comment in this code:

```
Thread.new do
  loop do
    @queue.synchronize {
      cond.wait_until { @queue.has_data? || @queue.finished? }
    }
    # some processing code that can also call @queue.enqueue
  end
end
```

Your comment that mentions "some processing code that can also call @queue.enqueue", is this the only place where `@queue.enqueue` is called? If so, then all of the threads will be blocked on the condition variable and none will be able to get to the point to be able to call enqueue. Im sure Ruby can detect that all threads are locked on the same entity and none are available to release it, thus deadlock.

If you do indeed have a separate thread that only enqueues (which would be a typical producer/consumer situation) make sure that it doesnt also wait on the condition variable, which could also cause deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to help you because you are only posting code fragments...

You should try the [work_queue](http://gemcutter.org/gems/work_queue) gem, or at least take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/fmmfonseca/work_queue/blob/master/lib/work_queue.rb).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to wait for has_data? || finished? in synchronize block. The code should look like:

```
Thread.new do
  loop do
    cond.wait_until { @queue.has_data? || @queue.finished? }
    enq = nil
    @queue.synchronize {
        enq = @queue.pop
    }
    # some processing code that can also call @queue.enqueue
  end
end
```

In that case you lock other threads only when operating with queue content. What you need to do is to synchronize on queue state change, like finished

A better solution is to wrap all thread critical variables with mutex, like [here](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#M000054) in rails. It'll make code a little bit slower since it eliminate simultaneous variable access.

Comment: I do have to synchronize on the queue, otherwise I get `current thread not owner`. I was thinking of doing it with mutexes, but the code would be much more understandable with Monitor if I only I can make it work...

Comment: The actual problem is that using wait_until you are locking all the threads to wait for some variable, that's deadlock. If you need to lock it, you need to lock inside wait_until not outside. As i've mentioned, you can make wrapper for mutex attrs/methods access to clean up implementation

Comment: wait_until releases the underlying mutex while its waiting

Comment: As @FrederickCheung mentions,  wait_until must unlock the mutex, and the mutex must be locked when wait_until is called (otherwise its probably undefined behaviour). It works this way with linux pthread cond_vars and mutex in c as well.